# Array.map function isn't applying to Object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to re-map an Object that comes from an API call.
The format of the response is the following:

```
data: {
    foo: [{
        id: "1",
        name: "joe",
        info: "whatever"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        name: "anna",
        info: "whatever"
    },...],
    bar: [...]
}
```

The code I'm using to re-map the object inside each response array is:

```
const DATA = response.data;
const entries = Object.entries(DATA);

for (const entry of entries) {
    entry[1].map(entry => ({
        id: entry["id"],
        mixed_info: entry["name"] + ", " + entry["info"]
    }));
}
```

When I console.log the data after this, it shows the same as the initial response, as if it completly ignored the map function.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You need to assign the result of your `map()` function to something.

Comment: .map() creates a new array with the result.
var updatesEntry = entry[1].map()......

Comment: While my answer is *factually correct* it's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve, if you make that clear I can revise my answer to show how to achieve it.

Comment: as already spotted you should exploit the map return value, moreover the `for of` does not provide references, but copies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the result of the `map` call:

```
entry[1] = entry[1].map(...);
```

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array - it doesn't modify the original.

Answer (score 2):

`map` *returns* a new array, you are ignoring the result of the call.

Comment: I completly forgot, my bad. Thanks, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign the `entry`:

```
  entry[1] = entry[1].map(/*...*/);
```

However that will only get reflected to the array inside `entries`, it won't change `DATA`. To change that, you have to either turn the key value pairs back into an object at the end:

```
  DATA = Object.fromEntries(entries);
```

Or you have to reassign the DATA properties while iterating:

```
   DATA[ entry[0] ] = entry[1].map(/*...*/);
```

---

I'd do:

```
  const { data } = response;

  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
     data[key] = value.map(/*...*/);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let result = {};
    for (const entry of entries) {
        result[entry[0]] = entry[1].map(entry => ({
            id: entry.id,
            mixed_info: `${entry["name"]  }, ${  entry["info"]}`,
        }));
    }
```

'result' contains exact remapped object.